# plotchar only on 1day timeframe tradingview - 'cannot call plotchar with arguments' error

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to display a plotchar only in 1day timeframe

```
_display = if (timeframe.period == 'D')
    1
else
    0

plotchar(data2, char="▼", display = _display)
```

But I get an error:

> line 24: Cannot call 'plotchar' with arguments (series[bool], char=literal string, display=bool); available overloads: plotchar(series[bool], const string, input string, input string, series[color], input integer, series[integer], const string, series[color], const bool, const string, input integer, const integer, string) => void; plotchar(fun_arg__<arg_series_type>, const string, input string, input string, fun_arg__<arg_color_type>, input integer, series[integer], const string, fun_arg__<arg_textcolor_type>, const bool, const string, input integer, const integer, string) => void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display argument can accept only 2 parameters atm - `display.none` or `display.all` and it specifies *where* the plot is displayed (chart, datawindow)

If you want to display a series only on 1D timeframe you can create a conditional in the `series` argument:

```
plotchar(timeframe.period == 'D' ? data2 : na, char="▼")
```